# Convert hash.digest() to unicode

Tags: python, unicode, unicode-string

```
import hashlib
string1 = u'test'
hashstring = hashlib.md5()
hashstring.update(string1)
string2 = hashstring.digest()

unicode(string2)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 1: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

The string HAS to be unicode for it to be any use to me, can this be done?
Using python 2.7 if that helps...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The result of `.digest()` is a bytestring¹, so converting it to Unicode is pointless. Use `.hexdigest()` if you want a readable representation.

¹ Some bytestrings can be converted to Unicode, but the bytestrings returned by `.digest()` do not contain textual data. They can contain any byte including the null byte: they're usually not printable without using escape sequences.

Answer (score 21):

Ignacio just gave the perfect answer. Just a complement: when you convert some string from an encoding which has chars not found in ASCII to unicode, you have to pass the encoding as a parameter:

```
>>> unicode("órgão")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> unicode("órgão", "UTF-8")
u'\xf3rg\xe3o'
```

If you cannot say what is the original encoding (UTF-8 in my example) you really cannot convert to Unicode. It is a signal that something is not pretty correct in your intentions.

Last but not least, encodings are pretty confusing stuff. This [comprehensive text about them](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) can make them clear.

Comment: why unicode("órgão", "UTF-8") is not working in my Python 2.7 environment?

Comment: @superche Maybe you are using another encoding in your terminal. What is the output of `print repr("órgão")` in your machine?